# Two counts in one query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help in making only one query out of these two queries:

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @listid) + ' AS listid, optout, COUNT(*)  AS nbEmail, ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @date, 120) + ''' AS date
            FROM list_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @listid) + '.dbo.members (NOLOCK) 
            GROUP BY optout

SET @SQL2 = 'SELECT ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @listid) + ' AS listid, Optout, COUNT(*) AS nbSMS, ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @date, 120) + ''' AS date
             FROM list_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @listid) + '.dbo.sms_members (NOLOCK) 
             GROUP BY Optout
```

The thing I need is two columns with each count but instead of the two queries. 
The 'listid' is going to be the same, the output also and same for the date

Thanks a lot

EDIT :

I want the result to be something like :

```
listid | Optout | nbEmail | nbSMS | Date
-------+--------+---------+-------+----------
  902  |   56   |   23    |  36   | 22/10/17
  902  |   45   |   27    |  16   | 22/10/17
  902  |   14   |   22    |  96   | 22/10/17
```

Comment: CROSS JOIN, or UNION ALL.

Comment: That looks very open to SQL Injection there.

Comment: @Larnu i didn't show you all the code ! Why do you say so ?

Comment: Also varchar with no length is a [bad habit](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). And while I don't condone NOLOCK because it has so many ugly things with it if you are going to use query hints you MUST use the WITH keyword because omitting it is deprecated.

Comment: I would agree with @Larnu that this looks wide open to sql injection. But maybe the listid variable is an integer? That would minimize the risk but I would at the very least incorporate quotename into the database name as a precaution.

Comment: String concatenation like `SET @SQL = 'SELECT '+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@listid)+' AS...` is very easy to inject into. For example, if `@listid` isn't an `integer` (which it could be) then someone could easily use the value `1; CREATE LOGIN TestLogin WITH PASSWORD = '123', CHECK_POLICY = OFF, CHECK_EXPIRY = OFF;--'` and maybe create a new login. Ideally you should be using parametrisation and `sp_executesql`, and `QUOTENAME` (as @SeanLange also suggested).

Comment: UNION ALL doesnt work in my case because i need two columns for each count !

Comment: Why doesn't UNION ALL work here? You have the same columns in both queries. Seems like exactly what you need. I didn't comment on that part ever because I figured it was taken care of already.

Comment: Please post desired output.  Based on your queries, a UNION ALL would work perfectly.   Your comment about needing two columns doesn't make sense since both counts are aliased "AS nb".   Your question is currently too unclear to try to answer.

Comment: @TabAlleman sean Lange ! i've just updated my question !

Answer (score 0):

Write a FULL OUTER JOIN on `optout` between the two tables, and COUNT DISTINCT PK values from each table to get the two counts.

Comment: something like that :    SET @SQL = 'SELECT '+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@listid)+' AS listid, optout, count(DISTINCT(*)) AS nb, '''+CONVERT(varchar,@date,120)+''' AS date
   FROM list_'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@listid)+'.dbo.members (NOLOCK)
   FULL OUTER JOIN list_'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@listid)+'.dbo.sms_members (NOLOCK) ON optout = list_'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@listid)+'.dbo.members (NOLOCK).optout
   GROUP BY optout

Comment: Yes, except not `DISTINCT(*)`  You didn't share DDL, so I don't know your table's PK, but if it were `ID` for example it would be `DISTINCT(a.ID)` for the table aliased "a".   Don't do JOINs without aliases.   It's messy.